# Using different DNS server via different interface to resolve different domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name

My VM has 2 interfaces, `eth1` & `eth2` and I need to resolve 2 domain names `*.abc.exanple` and `*.xzy.example`

For `*.abc.example` I want to use DNS server `192.0.2.1` via `eth1`
For `*.xyz.example` I want to use DNS server `192.0.2.2` via `eth2`

Much appreciate if you can advise me a solution as simple as possible since I'm quite new to Linux :-)
Host file is is not an option, since I have to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run your own DNS server locally on that server, you can create conditional forwarders for these two domains. Using static routing you can force traffic for `192.0.2.1` to leave `eth1` and traffic destined to `192.0.2.2` to leave `eth2`.

For BIND9, a sample (snippet) configuration would be:

```
zone "abc.example" {
   type forward;
   forwarders { 192.0.2.1; };
};
zone "xyz.example" {
   type forward;
   forwarders { 192.0.2.2; };
};
```